# Google Analytics how to get Access token with server to server OAuth with php

Tags: oauth, google-analytics

I'm trying to create a Dashboard for Google Analytics data but I don't know how I can combine the scripts.

I have to use Server to Server authentication like this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php but I'm unable to get an access token for my Javascript authentication

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
   serverAuth: {
      access_token: >>How to get an Access token from PHP<<
   }
});
```

If I just do something like this

```
$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/Service.json';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
var_dump($client->getAccessToken())
```

My getAccessToken is always NULL is there any other method to receive a Access Token with a server to server connection? I have to find method that doesn't require a login via Javascript since all backend users from the content management system should be able to see the data.

Thank you very much. I'm new to this, it would be very kind if you could explain how it works and not just sending a link

Edit: To say it in other words here is my entire code... why does it not work, what is wrong? Please help me

```
    <?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$accessToken = initializeAnalytics();

function initializeAnalytics()
{
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/Service.json';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
  return $accessToken;
}

?>

<script>
    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
      g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
      js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
    }(window,document,'script'));
</script>


<div id="chart-1-container"></div>

<script>
    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
          serverAuth: {
            access_token: '<?php echo $accessToken ?>'
          }
        });

        var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                ids: "ga:128053216",
                metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                dimensions: 'ga:date',
                'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday',
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'chart-1-container',
                type: 'LINE',
            }
        });
        dataChart.execute();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you need to make one request I think before its going to fetch a new access token.  Try and have php make a request to something.

Comment: could you pls make an example? I'm a little bit lost.

Answer (score 5):

Finally found a solution after days of trying....
it works now with this script

```
    <?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$accessToken = initializeAnalytics();

function initializeAnalytics()
{
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/Service.json';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);

  $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
  $token = $client->getAccessToken();
  $accessToken = $token['access_token'];

  return $accessToken;
}

?>

<script>
    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
      g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
      js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
    }(window,document,'script'));
</script>


<div id="chart-1-container"></div>

<script>
    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
          serverAuth: {
            access_token: '<?php echo $accessToken ?>'
          }
        });

        var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                ids: ">your analytics ID<",
                metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                dimensions: 'ga:date',
                'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday',
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'chart-1-container',
                type: 'LINE',
            }
        });
        dataChart.execute();
    });
</script>
```